# How do I create tar.7z file from the command line?

Tags: tar, compression, 7zip

I would like to zip up my homework from last year. How do I tar and zip the whole folder from command line Ubuntu (I don't have GUI).

Answer (score 30):

Use the following one-liner:

```
tar cf - <source folder> | 7z a -si <Destination archive>.tar.7z
```

Comment: Potential source: `man 7z`.

Answer (score 12):

It is **not** a good idea compressing directly with 7z spcially on unix/linux  systems: 7z **does not preserve permissions and or user/group info**. So: first tar, and then compress.

As reported on 7zip wiki page at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7z#Limitations :

> Limitations
>
> The 7z format does not store filesystem permissions (such as UNIX
>   owner/group permissions or NTFS ACLs), and hence can be inappropriate
>   for backup/archival purposes. A workaround on UNIX-like systems for
>   this is to convert data to a tar bitstream before compressing with 7z.

Answer (score 9):

Read `man tar`. It offers:

```
     -a, --auto-compress
       use archive suffix to determine the compression program
     -j, --bzip2
     --lzip
     --lzma
     --lzop
     -z, --gzip, --gunzip --ungzip
     -Z, --compress, --uncompress
```

Or, if none of those is right for you, and you have a compression program that reads `stdin`, you could:

```
tar cf- $HOME | my_compression_program >/tmp/compressed.output
```

Note that I'm writing the output somewhere other than `$HOME` (backing up into a directory that you're backing up leads to unconstrained file growth).

Or, you could read `man 7z` - it looks like you could do

```
dir="directory to save"
7z a -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=32m -ms=on /tmp/archive.7z $dir
```

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest that you use:

```
tar cf - foldername | 7z a -si -m0=lzma2 -mx=3 foldername.tar.7z
```

for dramatic speedup increase.

It has the advantage of using lzma2 (`-m0=lzma2`) (which utilizes max available cores on your system and "Fast compression" preset (`-mx=3`), which is basically fast and good enough.
Note that LZMA2 is not only utilizing all cores on compression, but also on decompression.

Comment: Finally, with your answer, I've found what I was looking for: the ability to use all processors on the task.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `tar -Jchf <Filename>.tar.xz <Files to compress>`

The `-J` uses the XZ compression algorithm, the same as 7zip

`-c` creates a new file
`-h` preserves simlinks
`-f` sets the filename

Comment: I have checked with -J, it reduce double size in sql database file.